# REGEX for Matching img tag within arbitrary number of nested custom tags

Tags: php, regex, parsing, custom-tags

I am writing a message board that allows for quoting and quote chaining of other users. The message board allows certain html tags including the `<img>`. When a message is quoted, I want to find the `<img>` and replace the picture with a thumbnail. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
 $pattern = "<quote msgid=\"t,(\d+),(\d+)@(\d+)\" from=\"([A-z0-9_\.-]+)\" posted=\"(\d+)\">(.+)<img src=\"https?:\/\/i\.(minus|imgur)\.com\/([A-z0-9_\.-]+)\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)\"( \/)?>";
 $replace = "<div class=\"quoted-message\" msgid=\"t,$1,$2@$3\"><div class=\"message-top\">From: $4 | Posted: $5</div>$6<img src=\"http:\/\/$7.com\/$8s\.$9\" />";
 $encoded = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $encoded);
?>
```

The pattern itself works but the problem I am running into is that it does not play nice with nested quotes. For example the data can look like this:

```
<quote msgid="t,1234,3456@0" from"user" posted="test">Some words here<quote msgid="t,5635,57456@0" from"user2" posted="test">Some more <b>words</b> here<quote msgid="t,1243532,3452@0" from"user" posted="test">Something else here<img src="linktoimage"/></quote>some words can go here</quote>or here</quote>
```

My current regex will replace the first 3 Opening quote tags with one div tag instead of just matching the most inner tag. I know it has to do with the `(.+)` but I don't know what else I can do in order to check for preceding data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are not very suitable for your situation ([very oddly explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)). You should really use a parser.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the input and entertaining explanation. I will look into parsers.

Answer (score 0):

`(?!<quote.*?<quote)(<quote)`

Matches the inner most quote tag.

http://regexr.com?30ng2

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the image tag wont necessarily be in the inner most tag.